# Unwanted characters when writing output from SQL query inside tcolorbox

Tags: python-3.x, latex, jinja2

I am using python3, MariaDB, Jinja2 and LaTeX +tcolorbox. I am trying to write the output from an SQL query inside a tcolour box but it is showing it inside (' ',) as shown in the following screenshot:

[showing (’10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1’,)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNRa1.png)

How can I remove the unwanted characters? Thank you. Please see the code included below.

**testdb.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import jinja2
import os
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","test","password")
cursor = connection.cursor()


# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
connection.close()

from jinja2 import Template
latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    block_start_string = '\BLOCK{',
    block_end_string = '}',
    variable_start_string = '\VAR{',
    variable_end_string = '}',
    comment_start_string = '\#{',
    comment_end_string = '}',
    line_statement_prefix = '%%',
    line_comment_prefix = '%#',
    trim_blocks = True,
    autoescape = False,
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath('.'))
)

template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('tcsqltest.template')

print(template.render(section1="SQL query : %s " % data, data1=data, section2='SQL query shown inside tcolorbox example.'))
```

**tcsqltest.template**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
An example document using \LaTeX, Python, SQL, tcolorbox  and Jinja2.
\section{\VAR{section1}}
%# This is a sql database query output
\section{\VAR{section2}}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[space to upper,
        skin=bicolor,
        colbacklower=black!75,
        collower=white,
        title={Top Title},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        halign lower=flush right,
        bottom=0mm,
        height=3cm
    ]

        \VAR{data1}

        \tcblower
        End-Title
    \end{tcolorbox}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.fetchone()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) method returns a sequence; in this case, a tuple. And in this case a 1-tuple. So you can grab the first and only item of that 1-tuple by doing this instead:

```
data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: That was fast and simple. Works beautifully. Thank you so much. I had tried other code prior to this and learned it was a tuple but still wasn't sure how to fix it. Thank you. I up-voted your answer but as I am a new user it didn't count it.

Comment: You're very welcome. You made it really easy to resolve because you put so much work into your question. You can accept the answer with the checkmark. That way people know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you. I have pressed the checkmark now. I don't even remember seeing it earlier.